# VB.NET Count bits, 1's are counted as 1, Zero's are counted together in a sequence between 1's

Tags: vb.net, binary, counting

Looking to count bits in a sequence.

1's are counted as 1, Zero's are counted together in a sequence between 1's

If you look at this picture 
[image: pic]

The output should be 2,1,5,1,1,3,2,1

Here is my code it works on 80% of numbers sometimes it messes up.

```
dim bitmask() as byte
redim bitmask(15)
bitmask(0) = 0
bitmask(1) = 0
bitmask(2) = 1
bitmask(3) = 0
bitmask(4) = 0
bitmask(5) = 0
bitmask(6) = 0
bitmask(7) = 0
bitmask(8) = 1
bitmask(9) = 1
bitmask(10) = 0
bitmask(11) = 0
bitmask(12) = 0
bitmask(13) = 1
bitmask(14) = 0
bitmask(15) = 1


Public Function GetBitCount() As Byte()
    Dim count As Byte = 0
    Dim bitcounts As New List(Of Byte)
    Dim indexOfNext As Integer = 0
    Dim totalCounted As Integer = 0
    While True
        indexOfNext = Array.IndexOf(bitmask, CByte(1), indexOfNext + 1)

        If indexOfNext > 0 Then
            If indexOfNext - totalCounted = 1 Then
                bitcounts.Add(2)
                bitcounts.Add(1)
            ElseIf indexOfNext - totalCounted > 0 Then
                bitcounts.Add(IIf(totalCounted > 0, indexOfNext - totalCounted, indexOfNext))
            ElseIf indexOfNext - totalCounted > 1 Then
                bitcounts.Add(2)
                bitcounts.Add(1)
            Else
                bitcounts.Add(1)
                bitcounts.Add(1)
            End If
            If totalCounted = 0 Then bitcounts.Add(1)
            totalCounted = indexOfNext + 1
        Else
            Exit While
        End If
    End While
    If totalCounted - 1 > 2 AndAlso totalCounted - 1 < bitmask.Length - 1 Then
        bitcounts.Add(1)
        bitcounts.Add((bitmask.Length - 1) - (totalCounted - 1))
    ElseIf totalCounted - 1 <= 2 AndAlso totalCounted - 1 < bitmask.Length - 1 Then
        bitcounts.Add((bitmask.Length - 1) - (totalCounted - 1))
    Else
        bitcounts.Add(1)
    End If
    If count > 0 Then bitcounts.Add(count)
    Return bitcounts.ToArray()
End Function
```

Comment: Given the provided requirements description, the output listed is wrong for the provided picture.  The `10` near the end should be `1,1`, not `2`.  So the output matching the picture would be `2,1,5,1,1,3,1,1,1`.

Comment: "... sometimes it messes up".  You're going to need to be more descriptive than that. Does an error message/exception occur? On what line? Or does the output not what it should be?  If the latter, then please provide expected output and actual output for a given input.

Comment: But the `1,0` is counted as 2`` so its not wrong It's a custom binary format I made, it sometimes adds a extra element to the array for no reason, something funky with the Array.IndexOf I cannot get all cases in there without missing one.

Comment: Sorry I know the title is misleading by `1,0,1` I mean the count should be `2,1` It's not in a sequence between the 1's are zero's counted but the first 1 is counted and ignores the last one 1.

Comment: I solved it will post a solution my colors were off you are correct I was wrong.. the picture will be updated as well. My bit counting was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

```
Public Function GetBitCount() As Byte()
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim count As Byte = 0
    Dim bitcounts As New List(Of Byte)
    For i = 0 To bitmask.Length - 1
        If bitmask(i) = 1 Then
            bitcounts.Add(count)
            count = 0
        End If
        count += 1
    Next
    If count > 0 Then bitcounts.Add(count)
    Return bitcounts.ToArray()
End Function
```